# Lex pattern doesn't react to inputs

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I've defined the following aliases:

```
WS [ \t\n]
WSS {WS}*
NEWSS {WS}+
NAME [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_-]*
WORD [^;]+
VAR_USE ${WSS}{NAME}{WSS}:
VAR_DEF ${VAR_USE}{WSS}{WORD}{WSS};
```

And the two simple rules:

```
{VAR_DEF} cout << "VAR DEF";
{VAR_USE} cout << "VAR USE";
```

When I run the program and I start writing words, whenever I write words that should be detected by second rule, it just doesn't react until I write a word detected by the first rule. (It doesn't echo nor detected) 
For example here's a screenshot of a short run: 
[image]

First input is echoed, second input is detected by the second rule, third input should be detected by first rule but it doesn't. What may be the problem?

Comment: I don't see how that lex specification can produce that output. `VAR_DEF` requires two consecutive colons, and your input only has one.

Comment: Oops I copied it wrong. Though it still doesn't explain it doesn't being echoed.

Answer (score 1):

`VAR_USE` can only be matched if `VAR_DEF` fails (because it is a prefix of `VAR_DEF`). In order to fail, the suffix

```
{WSS}{WORD}{WSS};
```

must be unmatchable. But `{WORD}` matches any string not containing a semicolon, even if it includes a newline. If there is a semicolon somewhere in the input, `{VAR_DEF}` will match up to that semicolon. If not, `{VAR_DEF}` will fail and the lexer will fall back to `{VAR_USE}`, but the scanner can't tell that there is no following semicolon until it reaches the end of the input. (I.e. when you type ctl-D followed by Enter.).

Comment: I see, so how can I make lex take {VAR_USE} so it'll match when it sees string that ends with ":" but can't find currently a longer matching rule?

Comment: @enemy: start by clearly specifying what "not matching" means.